# Master Login On HTML Website?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I would like to implement a master login for my website just like the login methodology in CNN.com, if you try to register a user on CNN.com and after successfully login, open a link on the site, you will notice that the page will first load and still that your login name is not available yet, after that a small refresh happens to the page and the login name is populated. I would like to program a similar technique on my HTML website, Could it be that they are using PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

They are using php sessions.

Good tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: It seems that they actually uses JSON not php, of course we reached this conclusion after analyzing their page using firebug.

Comment: JSON is a way of communicating between the client and the server. PHP is the program running on the server. Two different things!

Comment: @YahyaKH, Unless they're storing everything by IP in databases, they're probably using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you mentioned what environment you're coding in (ASP.NET? PHP?), and what your capabilities/strengths are. In other words, will you be able to add code with ease based on general instructions about what to do, or are you looking for a complete copy-paste-then-perhaps-correct-a-little solution?

EDIT:
I would have added this as a comment, but the site won't let me :)